# sampling multivariate uniform in PyMC3

Tags: pymc, pymc3

I would like to use sample from a custom distribution with uniform prior using `DensityDist`. Something in spirit of:

```
import theano.tensor as T
from pymc3 import DensityDist, Uniform, Model

with Model() as model:
    lim = 3
    x0 = Uniform('x0', -lim, lim)
    x1 = Uniform('x1', -lim, lim)

    x = T.concatenate([x0,x1])
    # Create custom densities
    star = DensityDist('star', lambda x: star(x[:,0],x[:,1]))
```

Where `star` is an function mapping a 2D cartesian point to an un-normalized log-likelihood function.  It is the function I want to sample from using Metropolis-Hastings.

I tried a number of variations but none worked. The current code fails with:

```
ValueError: The index list is longer (size 2) than the number of dimensions of the tensor(namely 0). You are asking for a dimension of the tensor that does not exist! You might need to use dimshuffle to add extra dimension to your tensor.
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index to `x` is wrong. It is only one dimensional, so indexing along two dimensions can't really work.

```
import theano.tensor as tt
from pymc3 import DensityDist, Uniform, Model

def star(x):
    return -0.5 * tt.exp(-tt.sum(x ** 2))
    # or if you need the components individually
    #return -0.5 * tt.exp(-x[0] ** 2 - x[1] ** 2)

with Model() as model:
    lim = 3
    x0 = Uniform('x0', -lim, lim)
    x1 = Uniform('x1', -lim, lim)

    x = T.stack([x0,x1])
    # Create custom densities
    star = DensityDist('star', star)
```